Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTVLCPlayer" was not found in the UIManager
I'm trying to use the react-native-vlc-media-player library and I have implemented the code as described in the library docs in npm but whenever I get to the screen I implemented the player on I get the error;
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTVLCPlayer" was not found in the UIManager
I'm working with;
react-native version 0.74.1
expo version 51
and currently developing for android.
I would appreciate any help on this, please.
I have tried upgrading the expo version from version 50 to 51 and followed the solution provided in this github gist but none has solved the issue.
I also have react-native-vlc-media-player added to the plugins array in app.json.

Have you rebuild a development build after the package installation? If not, i suggest you do that.
